# What's wrong with Hello World in scala?

Tags: java, scala, scala-3

I am learning `scala` from docs.scala-lang.org. There is an [example](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/hello-world-2.html)

```
object HelloYou extends App {
    if (args.size == 0)
        println("Hello, you")
    else
        println("Hello, " + args(0))
}
```

After compiling with `scalac` I run `scala HelloYou Al` and get

> java.lang.NullPointerException

followed by

> ```
>     at java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Native Method)
>     at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.size$extension(ArrayOps.scala:197)
>     at HelloYou$.<clinit>(HelloYou.scala:2)
>     at HelloYou.main(HelloYou.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ```

What's wrong? It's my first experience of a language where `Hello, World` is not working...

Details

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 3.1.1 -- Copyright 2002-2022, LAMP/EPFL

java -version
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You are tring the example for Scala 2 but you are running Scala 3.

Comment: @sarveshseri Isn't scala back compatible, at least in basic syntax?

Comment: @yarchik: My guess is that like Python, Scala doesn't give two hoots about backwards compatibility. They could learn a lot from a good old-fashioned language like C.

Comment: Scala 3 is too different from Scala 2. Yes, they tried to consever most of the syntax, but there are many things which have changed. Scala 3 is kind of an attempt to re-imagine Scala. Also, this particular way of defining the entry point was very much disliked by people, so it was pretty much destined to go away.

Comment: Even in Scala 2 this was recognized as a crappy way to implement an entry point. Happy to see it was removed from 3.

Comment: @NathanHughes "a crappy way to implement an entry point", can you elaborate please? I noticed many people have the same opinion.

Comment: @yarchik `App` does some weird compliler magic to get its body moved into the `main` method and still have access to the args... as I said, it was never a good idea, it was an attempt to make the language more approachable by newcomers so you didn't have to do all the ceremony of a `main` but IMHO, while the intention is good, the tradeoff was not worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the command-line arguments like that is no longer supported in Scala 3:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html

Comment: Very nice, but why compiler is not complaining?

Comment: @yarchik: The args method is still there in the App trait, it is just not initialized anymore. I agree, it is really confusing.

Comment: According to your link the recommended way is to use @main methods. However, I met a problem with standard example again. See my follow up post https://stackoverflow.com/q/71026368/4954079

Answer (score 2):

`App` was never a good idea to begin with, just write a normal `main` method.

```scala
object HelloYou:
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    args.toList match
      case Nil =>
        println("Hello, you")

      case name :: Nil =>
        println(s"Hello, ${name}")

      case _ =>
        println("Hello, you all")
  end main
end HelloYou
```

Comment: By the way, I never get `case Nil` activated. Why is it needed?

Comment: @yarchik The `Nil` case is for when there are no arguments.

Comment: With my compiler the case without arguments goes to `case name :: Nil `, strange...

Comment: @yarchik yeah just replicated the issue, it seems that for some reason the **Scala 3** CLI runner pass the class name as an argument, making the `Nil` case unreachable and the second case wrong. However, that was not the case of the **Scala 2** CLI runner, nor is the behavior you would get if you compile it to a **JAR** and run it using a **JRE** directly. This feels like a bug in the runner script.

Comment: @yarchik Uhm I think it would be better to just raise an issue in the **dotty** repo: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty

Comment: I agree about writing a normal main method instead of using `App`, but I think `@main` might be nicer here, especially for a newcomer.

Comment: @user I have had similar bad experiences with `@main` and **Scastie** I personally just desisted on those nice goodies. I, as an educator in formation, admire the idea / effort of trying to make the good old _"hello world"_ as simple as possible; but IMHO, all the approaches have failed and I would rather avoid them.