# Command line arguments in scala

Tags: java, scala

Recently I posted a question about some basic scala code. I got some useful responses that emphasized that scala2 and and scala3 are very different programming languages. Since I have scala3, I was careful enough to work out only scala3 examples, such as [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html) one:

```
@main def happyBirthday(age: Int, name: String, others: String*) =
  val suffix =
    age % 100 match
    case 11 | 12 | 13 => "th"
    case _ =>
      age % 10 match
        case 1 => "st"
        case 2 => "nd"
        case 3 => "rd"
        case _ => "th"
  val bldr = new StringBuilder(s"Happy $age$suffix birthday, $name")
  for other <- others do bldr.append(" and ").append(other)
  bldr.toString
```

I compile it as `scalac happyBirthday.scala`  and run as `scala happyBirthday 23 Lisa Peter`

> Illegal command line: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: "happyBirthday"`

This reminded me very much the issue observed in a comment to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025786/4954079). @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested that a workaround could be to compile to `jar`. I did exactly that using [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30581404/4954079)

```
scalac happyBirthday.scala -d happyBirthday.jar
```

and run

```
java -jar happyBirthday.jar 23 Lisa Peter
```

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/CommandLineParser$ParseError

I wonder what's wrong with this code? Notice that "@main methods are the recommended scheme to generate programs that can be invoked from the command line in Scala 3." according to this [reference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html).

Comment: Your JAR doesn't include the **Scala** stdlib, thus it is not unable as it is. You would need to use a build tool like **sbt** and create an assembly JAR in order to run it as a stand-alone application. - The other option would be to manually put the **Scala** JARs on the classpath, or run your code using the **Scala** command.

Comment: Similar starter questions on https://users.scala-lang.org/. The web site for the new tool is https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/ that is for trying out code. Everyone likes it.